# How to get addressee from SMS received on a phone with two sim cards?

Tags: android, sms, pdu

My application receives SMS. I can easily parse it with `createFromPdu` method. But result object doesn't contain property, which allows to get addressee number from SMS. I think that raw PDU may contain this information.

How could I extract it?

I would like to do it to support work with 2-sim phones. The code below works well, but just with phone with one sim card:

```
TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
phonenumber = mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Comment: @AH., unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for dual slim as for today. Thats mean - there is no any official public API available.

[Issue 14799:   Dual SIM cards supporting](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14799)

Comment: Thanks. If I would like to support that just for some particular vendors (for ex., Samsung and HTC), can I find some API to implement that for particular devices?